# Disable library settings for contributor SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

How do I disable library setting for contribute users in SharePoint Online? 
Users just needs to upload and download files to the library.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the below steps:

- Go to Library Setting for which you want to set permission
- Click Permissions for this document library
- Click Stop Inheriting Permissions
- Add Users with View Only Access to this Document Library or Change
  Their Access to View Only

For detail explanation you can see [here](https://it.stonybrook.edu/help/kb/setting-permissions-on-a-document-library-in-sharepoint-office-365)

Comment: when you make it view only will you be able to upload and download files